# how to set height of div dynamically in css when the content in other td varies

Tags: html, css, angular, css-selectors

How to set the height of the divider based on other column content since the column can increase or decrease its width based on other columns.

I tried to add different class based on number of columns but did not work in all conditions

```
 <table>
    <td>
    First Name (Not editable)
    </td>
    <td>
    <div class="divider">
    </div>
    </td>
    <td>
    ABC
    </td>    
    </table>

    .divider{
   background: black;
    width:1px;
    min-height:20px
    }
```

Below is the image  what I am trying to achieve
[image]

Comment: May I ask why you are working with a custom div instead of using table borders between the different columns?

Comment: Not add a div, use .css to add a border-left to one td (or border-right to the another one). You can also use a td with width 1px and background-color (sometimes when we send a mail with .html you need use this last work-around)